# JSONObject Throwing NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, json, jsonexception

I am stuck and can't program further due to this stupid problem. I hope someone here can help.

```
    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_profile_details, "GET", params);
            // check your log for json response 
//Error Here    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());
```

**LogCat:**

```
04-02 01:50:51.008: E/JSON Parser(4920): Error parsing data 
org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be
converted to JSONObject
04-02 01:50:51.008: D/AndroidRuntime(4920): Shutting down VM
04-02 01:50:51.008: W/dalvikvm(4920): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x40c2d930)
04-02 01:50:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(4920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 01:50:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(4920): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 01:50:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(4920):     at
com.package.creatingdbconn.SignIn$2$1.run(SignIn.java:88)
```

Everytime when i compile this code and run it. It throws this error, the NullPointerExceptionError even after being initialized. I activate the piece of code under an action of a button but everything else works fine except these specific lines of code. jsonobject giving error for don't know what reason.

Comment: It looks like your json parser choked and returned `null`.  Check for `null` before you try to run `toString()` on `json`.

Comment: `json.toString()` ¿¿?? it's null, check your `json string response` and put string inside parenthesis, example `json.toString("name");` then it reports `name` from `json string`

Comment: `org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be
converted to JSONObject` check that you are not receiving html/xml instead of json

Comment: I hope that you have already seen that when json is being initialized through http request message. url_profile_details is reffering to a php file which is actually linked to my localhost. To get data from localhost to the real device is the responsibility of .php i think that php file is not working accordingly. Is it right?